# Custom attributes in Google Error Reporting shows up in logs but not on stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-error-reporting

We are logging errors using GCPLoggingClient. Making sure that the format of the logged objects is ReportedErrorEvent so that they get marked as google errors and show up in stackdriver error reporting. This works and we can get errors logged to stackdriver.

Any custom field that is added to ReportedErrorEvent shows up in the logs on logs explorer but not on stackdriver.

Is it that the representative errors formed by stackdriver only picks the attributes specified in [ReportedErrorEvent](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/report#reportederrorevent)? What could the cause for this be? Is there any way we can get these fields in the error groups formed on stackdriver?

Comment: If you are trying to set alerts based on your logs, there is a work around available for this you can import your logs to a big query and can trigger an alert based on the data that got inserted into the big query. Follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) for importing your logs to big query.